# Parallax scroll text jumps on top on first scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

Text jumps to the top on first scroll if the property is `position:fixed; top:500px or 40%` and its invisible, until first scroll if the property is `margin-top:500px;`

link to the site: http://www.pappu-lighting.com/Series/Kutiq/LAST.html
(the word GEOMETRY)

The code for it:

```
#seriq {
color:white;
z-index:9999;
position:absolute;
font-family:futuraat;
font-size:5vw;  
padding:0px;
top:70%;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
}
```

I want to make it visible from the beginning and not to jerk to the top.

Comment: z-index makes it come to top. If you remove it will go down the top Pappu Ateliers circle.

Comment: Do you want to move Geometry a bit down ??

Comment: You probably didn't understand me. It should be staying under the lamp the whole time, moving with it while scrolling.

Comment: When you get in the page the word is staying under the lamp. In the moment  you scrol for the first time it jerks right to the top

Comment: Yes got that now, what is the expected behaviour ??

Comment: It should be  under the lamp(box) and moving with the same speed as the lamp. They have to move together. When i change the property from  'top' to 'margin-top' it works, but when you get into the page the WORD is invisible until the first scroll.

Comment: I forgot it to put the word int <DIV>... when i did it everything became ok

Comment: okay, even using, position:sticky, margin-top:40%, z-index:9999 also works fine for this

Comment: its not working because its losing the parallax effect from the javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position:sticky;` for the element to stick to particular position as it scrolls and be visible throughtout

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position